# With CRF++, MIRA works for me but CRF-L1 and CRF-L2 do not

Tags: windows, crf++

It may not matter, but I am using the windows distribution of CRF++ 0.58.

So I have successfully used mallet to train a model with a CRF and then test it.  When I try to use the same train and test files with CRF++ (and after creating a template file), I get a

```
The line search routine mcsrch failed: error code:0
```

error when I use either

```
-a CRF-L1
```

or the default

```
-a CRF-L2
```

When I use

```
-a MIRA
```

though, training works without error and same with test.

The format of the test and training data can be the same for both mallet and crf++, so that is not the issue.  My template file is as simple as

```
#Mixed
M00:%x[0,0]
M01:%x[0,1]
M02:%x[0,2]
......
M12:%x[0,12]
```

My last column is either 0 or 1 in my training data which is the value to classify with. No whitespace in any of my features, I use underscores when necessary.  Am I missing something simple here, what would cause the L1 and L2 regularizations to fail like that?

Comment: Ah, the joys of LBFGS optimization. I can only say I sympathise because I've seen cryptic "line search terminated" messages so often (from various implementations) that I've simply given up on the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew it was something silly ...

To use features like I am using, you need to use the `U` prefix (as in Unigram).  So like `U00:%x[0,0]` is fine. You can't just call you features anything you want.

I also discovered that if I stripped down my test data to a single sentence, I would get the same error message.  When I restored my test data back to its original size of around 2600 sentences, the regularization algorithms now run.  Overfitting is a common cause of this error message across various nlp and ml applications, but that was not the true problem in my case.

Comment: How many features did you have originally? I realize that CRF++ functionality is limited in the total number of features it can handle. The reason for my comment is, I'm facing a similar error and was curious if my reasoning for facing the error is true. I have about 407837 features in all.

Answer (score 0):

It can also happen in the extreme case of a dataset with just one CLASS (due to bug in the training set generation procedure).